# MySQL select id where at least one value not in list

Tags: mysql, sql

I searched everywhere but couldn't find an answer. So right to the problem.

lets say I have a table like this

```
table1
+------+--------+
| id   | attr   |
+------+--------+
| 1    | weight |
| 1    | width  |
| 1    | length |
| 2    | width  |
| 2    | length |
+------+--------+
```

I would like a query to get the id of the row that is missing an attr.
In this case the id 2.

The attr to check against can be a list e.g. ('weight','width','length','height')
or a select e.g. SELECT DISTINCT attr FROM table1 WHERE id=1.

I have tried with NOT IN and NOT EXISTS but I can only get 0 or all results.

```
SELECT id FROM table1
 WHERE attr NOT IN ('weight', 'length', 'width','height')
```

and

```
SELECT  id
FROM    table1 t1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    table1 t2
        WHERE   t2.name NOT IN('weight', 'length', 'width','height')
    )
```

**EDIT**

if table is like

```
+------+--------+
| id   | attr   |
+------+--------+
| 1    | weight |
| 1    | width  |
| 1    | length |
| 1    | height |
| 2    | width  |
| 2    | length |
| 2    | other  |
+------+--------+
```

How can I get the following? ie. the missing attr for row id (id as I explained in the comments is just an alias not a primary key id)

```
+------+--------+
| id   | attr   |
+------+--------+
| 2    | width  |
| 2    | length |
+------+--------+
```

Comment: You should be aware that it defeats the purpose of an ID column if it is not unique.

Comment: The id here is for simplicity, just for demonstration purposes, could be something like product number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Here's one using aggregation:

```
select id
from table1
where attr in ('weight','length','width')
group by id
having count(distinct attr) <> 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: is there also a way to get the missing attr? Like:  |2 | weight  |

Comment: added an edit. Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` with `having` clause, e.g.:

```
select id
from table
where attr in ('weight','width','length')
group by id
having count(distinct(attr)) < 3
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer but sgeddes was faster so the accepted will go to him.